# REST Api Filtered odata returning error: list view threshold

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, odata

Why does the first query runs ok and the second throws list view threshold error?

Note that it's a regular `SP.ListTemplateType.tasksWithTimelineAndHierarchy` List with Id and PercentComplete as default and indexed columns.

Note also:
`/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('actions')/itemcount` equals to 7000 items:

```
items.filter(x => x.PercentComplete ==1) // equals 1000
items.filter(x => x.PercentComplete < 1) // equals 6000
```

**First Query**

```
/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('actions')/items?$filter= Id gt 4000&$top=4000
```

=>returns ok

**Second Query**

```
/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('actions')/items?$filter= Id gt 4000 and PercentComplete lt 1&$top=4000
```

returns=>

```
{"odata.error":
   {
   "code":"-2147024860, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQueryThrottledException",
   "message": {"lang":"en-US",
      "value":"The attempted operation is prohibited because 
      it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator."}
    }
}
```

Comment: great, @Akhoy! gonna index the column. brb

Comment: @Akhoy,  the PercentComplete column is a default column (from Tasks Content Type) and it's indexed by default, as is DueDate.... So, there is anothe reason...

Answer (score 1):

If you have list items more than 5000, or you are anticipating you might have items more than 5000 in the future then the best practice is to make rest call in more than 1 batches of 5000 starting from your top ID + 4999 and so on and stack it up in an array.

I'll show you an example how I have fetched data for 15000 items (you can do as per your requirement).

```
var itemStorageVariable =[];
var ListName = "actions";
function stackItems()
{
var checkTopIdFilter = "?$select = Id&$orderby=Id asc&$top=1";  \\your filter to get the top id
var callTrainingReqListCheckTopId = GetListItems(ListName , null, checkTopIdFilter);
$.when(callTrainingReqListCheckTopId).then(function (tData) {
        if (tData.d.results.length != 0) {
            var startId1 = tData.d.results[0].Id;
            var endId1 = startId1 + 4999;
            var startId2 = endId1 + 1;
            var endId2 = startId2 + 4999;
            var startId3 = endId2 + 1;
            var endId3 = startId3 + 4999;
            var startId4 = endId3 + 1;
            var endId4 = startId4 + 4999;
            var trFilter1 = "?$filter=((Id ge " + startId1 + ") and (Id le " + endId1 + "))&$top=5000";
            var trFilter2 = "?$filter=((Id ge " + startId2 + ") and (Id le " + endId2 + "))&$top=5000";
            var trFilter3 = "?$filter=((Id ge " + startId3 + ") and (Id le " + endId3 + "))&$top=5000";
            var callTrainingReqList1 = GetListItems(ListName, null, trFilter1);  //rest call to get data of first 5000
            var callTrainingReqList2 = GetListItems(ListName, null, trFilter2);  //rest call to get data of next 5000
            var callTrainingReqList3 = GetListItems(ListName, null, trFilter3);  //rest call to get data of next 5000
            $.when(callTrainingReqList1, callTrainingReqList2, callTrainingReqList3).then(function (trData1, trData2, trData3) {
                for (var i = 0; i < trData1[0].d.results.length; i++) {
                    itemStorageVariable.push(trData1[0].d.results[i]);   //pushing first 5000 data into array
                }
                for (var i = 0; i < trData2[0].d.results.length; i++) {
                    itemStorageVariable.push(trData2[0].d.results[i]);   //pushing next 5000 data into array
                }
                for (var i = 0; i < trData3[0].d.results.length; i++) {
                    itemStorageVariable.push(trData3[0].d.results[i]);   //pushing next 5000 data into array
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
function GetListItems(listName, id, filter) {
    var siteURL = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('" + listName + "')/items" + filter;
    return $.ajax({
        url: siteURL,
        async: false,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
    });
}
```

Now you can call this function **stackItems()** wherever you want and you get all the data in **itemStorageVariable**.

To access your data, run a loop through the length of your array and you will get each item in it.

Comment: I was able to modify your code to query a list with more than 5000 items

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment, though you have indexed the column, if the $filter query returns results more than 5000 items, it will give the error.

What you need to do is form a query where your $filter returns less than 5000

If you want more than 5000 items then REST API is not the method you can use